# Concatenating all matches from a join table into a column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

I have two **MySQL** tables (table_a and table_b) and a join table (table_c).

## Table Structures:

- table_a:

```
__________________
| table_a:       |
|----------------|
| id             |
| result_column  |
------------------
```

- table_b:

```
__________________
| table_b:       |
|----------------|
| id             |
| name           |
------------------
```

- table_c:

```
__________________
| table_c:       |
|----------------|
| id             |
| table_a_id     |
| table_b_id     |
------------------
```

## My Goal:

#### I want to find a query that will:

1. Iterate over every table_a record and get the table_a.id value
2. Find any records in table_c which have a matching table_c.table_a_id value
3. For each matching record in table_c get the table_c.table_b_id value
4. Find the record in table_b which has a matching table_b.id value
5. For that matching record in table_b get the table_b.name value
6. In table_a, concatenate each matched name value into the corresponding table_a.result_column

> Example:
>   Before the Query:

```
_______________________  _________________________________  ________________
| table_a:            |  | table_c:                      |  | table_b:     |
|---------------------|  |-------------------------------|  |--------------|
| id  | result_column |  | id  | table_a_id | table_b_id |  | id  | name   |
|-----|---------------|  |-----|------------|------------|  |-----|--------|
|  1  |               |  |  1  |      1     |      3     |  |  1  | Kevin  |
|  2  |               |  |  2  |      1     |      4     |  |  2  | Jesse  |
|  3  |               |  |  3  |      2     |      2     |  |  3  | Karen  |
-----------------------  |  4  |      3     |      1     |  |  4  | Tim    |
                         |  5  |      3     |      5     |  |  5  | Lauren |
                         ---------------------------------  ----------------
```

> After the Query:

```
_______________________  _________________________________  ________________
| table_a:            |  | table_c:                      |  | table_b:     |
|---------------------|  |-------------------------------|  |--------------|
| id  | result_column |  | id  | table_a_id | table_b_id |  | id  | name   |
|-----|---------------|  |-----|------------|------------|  |-----|--------|
|  1  | Karen, Tim    |  |  1  |      1     |      3     |  |  1  | Kevin  |
|  2  | Jesse         |  |  2  |      1     |      4     |  |  2  | Jesse  |
|  3  | Kevin, Lauren |  |  3  |      2     |      2     |  |  3  | Karen  |
-----------------------  |  4  |      3     |      1     |  |  4  | Tim    |
                         |  5  |      3     |      5     |  |  5  | Lauren |
                         ---------------------------------  ----------------
```

For absolute clarity, I understand that this is incredibly bad practice within  a relational data-table. This is as far from normalization as one can get. I would never design a database like this. I was tasked with creating a custom column with a list of values *purely* for a business case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you seem to want is:

```
select c.table_a_id, group_concat(b.name separator ', ') 
from c join
     b
     on c.table_b_id = b.id
group by c.table_a_id;
```

If you actually want to update `a`, you can put this into an `update` statement:

```
update a join
       (select c.table_a_id, group_concat(b.name separator ', ') as names
        from c join
             b
             on c.table_b_id = b.id
        group by c.table_a_id
       ) cb
       on cb.table_a_id = a.id
    set result_column = cb.names
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is close; but you also required that you only want the records matched in table C that are in A.

The first query does not meet this requirement; but the update statement does, as it will only update records in table A, if the id matches the table_a_id value pulled from table C.

Given what you said you wished for the end result, the update statement above would work.
If you wish to be explicit in your logic, just add a join from table A to table C.

```
select a.id, group_concat(b.name separator ', ') 
from a 
join c ON (a.id = c.table_a_id)
join b ON (c.table_b_id = b.id)
group by a.id;
```